# Distributions over circuits and N-to-N vs N-to-1 circuits

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, circuit-complexity, boolean-functions, pseudorandomness, natural-proofs

This is really a two part question, and they aren't necessarily related.  First, my understanding of natural proof barriers is that they are based on the idea that a suitable distribution over small circuits will "look like" a distribution over all functions, at least to someone with limited computational power.  So, are there specific models studied of random circuits, and proofs that they do indeed look pseudo-random?  The dialogue in Gowers' blog some time ago indicates some of the difficulty in choosing such a distribution, as at one point one of the speakers inadvertently creates a distribution (over formulas rather than circuits) which fails even some fairly simple tests as pointed out in the comments (see http://gowers.wordpress.com/2009/09/22/a-conversation-about-complexity-lower-bounds/ ).  For example, I know that there are results like [Mark Braverman](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~mbraverm/)'s [about polylog independence](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~mbraverm/Papers/FoolAC0v7.pdf), but are there results showing that a given circuit distribution produces an output with such polylog independence w.h.p?

Second question: is the state of the art any better on circuit lower bounds if we consider N-to-N functions rather than N-to-1 functions?  That is, are there explicit functions with N input bits and N output bits for which a superlinear bound is proven, where the results are better than what one can prove for functions with 1 output bit?  Would lower bounds on N-to-N functions be "almost as interesting" as those on N-to-1, or is this much less interesting?

Comment: Done.  It's somewhere in the middle of the "conversation".